# Performance improvement - Alternative for a map in xquery

Tags: xpath, xquery, bigdata, marklogic

I am using `cts:element-value-co-occurences` for a query which returns a big list of values. Since I am giving "`map`" as an option, those occurences are copied into a map(an example given below).

### Returned Map for the query

```
map:map(
<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map">
<map:entry key="doc">
  <map:value xsi:type="map:map">
  <map:map>
     <map:entry key="/data/fb/www.abcdefgh.com#form123456665364#thread123456968765#post987986513213_65434360536840613_66445444">
     <map:value xsi:type="xs:float">0.289406</map:value>
     </map:entry>
  </map:map>
  </map:value>
</map:entry>
</map:map>
)
```

As you notice, my map key is "`doc`", the occurences returned are copied into this key "`doc`" as `sub-map`.
The sub-map's "`<map:entry key=`" has a big URL as the key.

When one occurence/result is returned for the query, its good. The problem is when hundred's of result is returned, the performance is getting very worse. Is there any alternative for this? I am only concerned with the value "0.289406" than the big key.

can i get the value alone directly into any xml element as like :-

```
<doc>
 <valu>0.289406</valu>
 <valu>-0.23456</valu>
 <valu>0.3665</valu>
</doc>
```

instead of using a map or any iterations??

Comment: Please post some example data to work with.

Comment: err.. the above map is fetched from db, it is the sample. $doc-map:=cts:element-value-co-occurences("xdmp:document",..,"map","collation",$query) fetched the above map from db for the query.

Answer (score 0):

Hundreds of results should be fine. On a regular basis I work with thousands to millions of results in maps.

So I suspect something else is going on. If you can come up with a reproducible test case, someone may be able to spot the problem.